# How to efficiently restructure org-file by converting first level of plain list to headline?

Tags: org-mode

Consider the following minimal example of a subtree in a large org file:

```
#+STARTUP: indent 
* heading 1
- My favorite music
  - A
  - B
  - C
- My favorite food
  - D
* heading 2
** Movies  
- My favorite movies
  - E
  - F
    - additional note
- etc.
  - G 
** Series
- My favorite series
  - H
  - I
    - J
      - perhaps another note
- My favorite series actors
  - K
  - L
```

I'd like to convert the first level plain list items to subheadings. Like this:

```
#+STARTUP: indent 
* heading 1
** My favorite music
- A
- B
- C
** My favorite food
- D
* heading 2
** Movies  
*** My favorite movies
- E
- F
  - additional note
*** etc.
- G 
** Series
*** My favorite series
- H
- I
  - J
    - perhaps another note
*** My favorite series actors
  - K
  - L
```

After the conversion, the list items and headings should be properly indented.

I tried using C-c C-* in the plain list, but this converts all items to headings.
C-c * on the first heading works in principle, but the indentation is off and the plain list items below are indented as well, so I'd have to fix the indentation manually. Since the list is pretty long, the effort to convert all items manually in this manner would be too high.

Comment: Is this structure uniform? I.e. do you only have top-level headlines with each headline containing a two-level list? Is there text between the headline and the list? At first sight, I think it would work to convert each list into headings  in a first pass and then, in a second pass, convert third level headings back into lists. There might of course be a better/easier/faster method, but I think what I described could be done with two calls of `org-map-entries`, one for each pass.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The list is indeed not as uniform as I first thought and the problem might be more challenging to solve than expected. Some headlines contain sublevel headlines which contain plain lists. However, there are no third level headlines. Most of the plain lists are two-levels but some of them are also three-level lists. There is no text between headline and plain list.  I'm going to make some edits in the minimal example. Your first idea is good, but it would mean a lot of manual work. How to use 'org-map-entries'? I currently have very limited to none emacs-lisp skills.